# Adjusting CSS border without affecting div placement

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to adjust the margins on the `border-right` property I added to create a vertical border between two divs. When adjusting these margins in the class that produces the margin, I am affecting the margins of the whole div rather then just the border.

I've attempted to add a pseudo-class that would only affect the border but it has no affect to the border display.

How can I affect the margins of just the border?

```css
.border {
  border-right: 3px solid
}

.border:after {
  margin-left: 30px
}

.width {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class='width border'>
  <p> hello </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using a `background-color` in the pseudo-class to mimic a border. By making the `:after` content an absolutely positioned element of the now relative parent, `.mydiv`, we can pin the new "border" to be 30px away from the right edge of the parent, whatever its width may be.

```css
.mydiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
}

.border:after {
  margin-left: 30px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -30px;  
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='width border mydiv'>
  <p> hello </p>
</div>
```